# Sharepoint Designer 2013 password is incorrect

Tags: 2013, password, designer

I have a Windows VM with SharePoint Designer 2013 on it.  Regardless of what I do when I either select Edit List from within my companies SharePoint site or try to open from the File menu inside Sharepoint Designer I get the error "The userid or password is incorrect. Please try again" after entering my email and password.

First thought is, are you entering the right username and password, trust me I am.

Things I have tried, the obligatory uninstall and reinstall as well as a repair on SharePoint Designer 2013.  I have tried clearing the cache for office and making sure my username and password is correct in the credentials manager.  Also messed with the network protocol for my VM thinking that might have something to do with it.

You would think pass through would work because I am able to get to said Sharepoint no problem.

Any other suggestions are welcomed because I am out of ideas.

Comment: Did you change your password recently?

Comment: Have you tried running as administrator?

Comment: Which user account are you trying to login as?

Comment: Turns out Sharepoint Designer for some reason was not recognizing pass through and needed my app password from MFA to be entered.  Very odd error.  If anyone wants a more in depth explanation let me know.  Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Sharepoint Designer for some reason was not recognizing pass through and needed my app password from MFA to be entered. Very odd error. If anyone wants a more in depth explanation let me know. Thanks for all the help